# Variation on Select top n

Tags: sql-server

Is is possible to do a variation of select top n rows to select top n rows starting at a row other than 0.
My (mobile) app has limited resources and no server side caching available. The maximum rows returned is 100. I get the first 100 by select top 100. I would then like the user to be then able to request rows 101-200 and so on. The database data is static and the the re-query time negligible. 
Platform SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2):

[Here's an article](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/12/30/2652.aspx) which demonstrates such queries using the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function.

Answer (score 2):

```
;With CTETable AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column_Name DESC) AS ROW_NUM, * FROM TABLENAME WHERE <CONDITION>
)

SELECT Column_List FROM CTETable WHERE ROWN_NUM BETWEEN <StartNum> AND <EndNum>
```

Use your [startNum] and [EndNum] to be any series you want maybe 123 - 147 ! This will work well !